# foreach on selected rows SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table that is basically set up so there is an `id(UNIQUE),mapID,employe_ID,` and a value... it looks sort of like this

Table

```
ID    mapID       employee_id     value
1       1         1               Brian
2       1         1               617-555-5555
3       1         2               Boston Office
4       1         2               Mary
5       3         1               617-666-6666
6       3         2               New york office
```

I want to loop thru this table so "for each" same employee_id, I can do an insert statement into another table where it is setup a little cleaner.

Like this will give you rough idea of what i am trying to convey.

```
Select * from table where employe_id=1
foreach(item in aboveSelect)
{
   Insert into table2
}
```

Obviously this is not the correct syntex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't "foreach loop" over SQL data - use the data **as sets**. So in your case - do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ...., ColN
  FROM dbo.table 
  WHERE employee_id=1
```

Nice, fast, set-oriented....

Comment: ok marc_s are you sure this will create multiple records in table2 (foreach employe_id=1)

Comment: @djCool: if there **are** multiple rows in the source table that match this criteria (`WHERE employee_id=1`) - then most definitely **YES!** This SQL statement will insert as many rows into `table2` as there are rows in `table` that match the criteria

Comment: but what if i also want to add MAX(table3.id) i.e INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE3_ID, COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT MAX(TABLE3.ID),R1.COL1,T1.COL2,T1.COL3 FROM TABLE1,TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.EMPLOYE_ID=1

Comment: @djCool: then you'll get as many rows inserted into `Table2` as match the criteria - and one of the columns will be the `MAX(Table3.ID)` value - same value for each row inserted. Basically: just run the `SELECT` statement on its own - its output is **exactly** what gets inserted....

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop/cursor - you can do this as a single atomic statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT id, mapid, employee_id FROM table1
```

...this is also faster and cleaner that a cursor-based approach. Looping in SQL should be avoided unless there is no other option as SQL Server prefers a set-based approach to most problems.

Comment: ok Chris are you sure this will create multiple records in table2 (foreach employe_id=1)

Comment: Well, add a WHERE clause, and it will insert whatever it is you're selecting, which seems to be what you want to do?